# using sqlite database,trying to insert values

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sqlite

Sir,
   im working with sqlite database to store data dynamically.I have created database in terminal and added it to my project resources.In that database i have created a table named category.My problem is that when i run the app and trying to insert the values in a textfield,the app gets terminated giving an exception that there is no such table named category.Im new to this sqlite and i realy dont know why this exception occurs.Plese let me know wat is happening.i used the following coding..

```
- (void) addCategory{
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into Category(Categoryname, Fromquant,Toquant,Units) Values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [Categoryname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 2, [Fromquant doubleValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 3, [Toquant doubleValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [Units UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        CategoryID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

and  in database the table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Category"("CategoryID",INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"Categoryname"VARCHAR,"Fromquant"REAL,"Toquant"REAL,"Units"VARCHAR);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running query on the correct database?

Comment: Can somebody please edit the question for more visibility of code

Comment: [Anyone who uses the SQLite C API directly in an Objective-C app is a masochist.  Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Answer (score 4):

I think create Table command of urs is wrong. You have not mentioned the data type of the first field. Just remove the comma after the first field. Use the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE "Category"("CategoryID"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"Categoryname"VARCHAR,"Fromquant"REAL,"Toquant"REAL,"Units"VARCHAR);
```

I think, it'll work. Try out